Studio PWA development environment
I'm trying to learn how to work with pwa studio and I'm not used to Node + React stack.
I managed to run the application with the github + docker/run-docker but then I would like to have a functional working environment for example using the debugger system from my vscode IDE.
But I can't configure it, can someone explain to me how to activate debug mode?
Thanks in advance,
